# Postgresql getting other information from max tuple

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Say you have a table with studentID, class, grade. I want the maximum grade for each class. This is easy, just group by class and get max(grade). But the problem I'm having is how to also get the studentID.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049947/how-do-i-select-the-max-score-from-each-distinct-user-in-this-table

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an aggregate function, you could use window functions:

```
SELECT class, grade, studentId
FROM   (SELECT class, grade, studentId, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY grade DESC) rk
        FROM   students)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `distinct on` is a good way to go:

```
select distinct on (s.class) s.*
from students
order by s.class, s.grade desc;
```

However you probably want *all* students for each class with the maximum grade.  If so, Mureinik's solution is better.